# Can't stream both audio sources, only mic works

Tags: avconv

Why does the following code not stream both audio sources?

```
#!/bin/bash

INRES="1920x1080"
OUTRES="1280x720"
FPS="20"
QUAL="medium"

STREAM_KEY=$(cat ~/.twitch_key)

avconv -g 0 \
-f x11grab -s $INRES  -r "$FPS" -i :0.0+0,768 \
-f pulse -i "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo" \
-f pulse -i "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" \
-vcodec libx264 -s $OUTRES -preset $QUAL \
-acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 4 -qscale 1 -b 712k -bufsize 1024k \
-f flv "rtmp://live.justin.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
```

Comment: I wonder if you need to mix them first? http://libav.org/avconv.html

Comment: @slm mix them how?

Comment: In this part of the FAQ: http://libav.org/avconv.html#amix